# Save blob as a file in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am sending a `blob` using Ajax. I need to save it as a file in a model.

views.py

```
  class JobPostModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = JobPostModelSerializer
      parser_class = (FileUploadParser, )

      def create(self, request):
          data = dict() 
          data['user'] = request.user
          data.update(request.data)

          serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
          if serializer.is_valid():
              serializer.save()
              return Response({'success': 'Job Posted Successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
          else:
              return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class JobPostModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobPost
        fields = ("job_title", "job_description", "job_video")
```

Ajax.js

```
_postJob(e){
    var blob = this.video_blob;
    var job_title = $("#job_title").val();
    var job_description = $("#job_description").val();
    var cookie = getCookie('csrftoken');
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('job_title', String(job_title));
    formdata.append('job_description', String(job_description));
    formdata.append('job_video', blob);

    console.log(formdata.get('job_title'));
    console.log(formdata.get('job_description'));
    console.log(formdata.get('job_video'));

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/job-post/',
        type: 'post',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': cookie},
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (e){
            console.log(e);
        },  
        error: function(e){
            console.log(e);
        },  
    }); 
}   

}
```

The error I get is.

```
{"job_title":["Not a valid string."],"job_description":["Not a valid string."],"job_video":["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]}
```

Comment: Try sending  formdata.append("file",$("#file")[0].files[0]) instead of blob. Your input should be <input id="file" name="file" class="input-file" type="file">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is where you are trying to manipulate `request.data`

```
data = dict() 
data['user'] = request.user
data.update(request.data)
```

Use `copy` function to make a copy of request data and update it with `request.user` instead of vice versa. Like this

```
data = request.data.copy()
data['user'] = request.user
```

And remove `parser_class` attribute. It is doing no help because attribute for specifying parsers is `parser_classes` not `parser_class`.

Comment: That really worked, didn't think manipulating the `request.data` object would cause me hours of pain. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you. Actually request.data is an object of specially designed `QueryDict` class and should only be duplicated using `copy` method. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).